# How to unmangle a c++ symbol at run-time?

Tags: c++, ios

I have a debugging problem looking into a large c++ library running on an iOS device. I have a need to look at a bunch of mangled symbols from backtrace()/backtrace_symbols(), and I'd like to do the unmangling at runtime. Is c++filt linked to something that I can call at runtime, and in what header file is it defined?

Answer (score 3):

Boost has a demangle function that calls into the implementation-defined demangling API such as `__cxa_demangle`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the previous responder, he set me in the right direction. The answer I was looking for can be found here:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>  // needed for abi::__cxa_demangle
```